# Mostrar Lista GroupBy usando Lambda, na view. ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, expressões-lambda

Bem, estou com um pequeno grande problema aqui. Faço a consulta no banco usando `Lambda`, e uso a tag `GroupBy`,a consulta está trazendo objetos corretamente, o problema, é que eu não consigo mostrar na view. da um erro quando eu uso `IEnumerable<>` e quando eu tento usar `List` da erro tbm. porém, se eu não uso o `GroupBy`, mostra na tela, usando o `IEnumerable<>`, segue código:

**Controller**:

```
public ActionResult RelatorioDatadois(DateTime? dataInicio, DateTime? dataFim)
{
    ViewBag.dataInicial = dataInicio;
    ViewBag.dataFinal = dataFim;

    if (dataInicio == null && dataFim == null)
    {
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        var vrDb = db.VrDb.Where(v => v.DataSolicitacao >= dataInicio && v.DataSolicitacao <= dataFim && v.Situacao == Situacao.Finalizado).GroupBy(v => v.Veiculo.Id).ToList();
        var data = dataInicio;
        var dataF = dataFim;
        return View(vrDb);
    }
}
```

**View**:

```
@model IEnumerable<GaragemModel.Vr>

<div class="panel-heading">

    <ul class="list-inline">
        <li> <h4>Período:</h4></li>
        <li>@ViewBag.dataInicial Até</li>
        <li> @ViewBag.dataFinal</li>
    </ul>
</div>    

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Placa
            </th>

            <th>
                Descrição
            </th>
            <th>
                Combustivel Gasto
            </th>

            <th>
                Km Percorrido
            </th>
            <th>
                Gasto
            </th>    
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>    
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr class="odd gradeX">
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Veiculo.Placa)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Veiculo.Descricao)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mv.Consumo) Litros
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mv.QuilometrosPercorridos) Km
                </td>
                <td>
                    R$ @ViewBag.TotalValorEmDinheiro
                </td>
            </tr>
        }    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

O erro Quando uso `IEnumerable<>`:

> O item de modelo inserido no dicionário é do
>   tipo'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Int32,GaragemModel.Vr]]',
>   mas esse dicionário requer um item do tipo
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[GaragemModel.Vr]'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando utiliza o `GroupBy` na sua consulta [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) está a modificar o tipo de dados do resultado, logo, se está a definir que a informação deverá ser no formato `IEnumerable<GaragemModel.Vr>` não pode trazê-la agrupada com outro tipo.

---

Experimente fazer da seguinte forma:

### Controller

```
var vrDb = (from x in db.VrDb
            where x.DataSolicitacao >= dataInicio
            && v.DataSolicitacao <= dataFim
            && v.Situacao == Situacao.Finalizado
            group x by x.Veiculo.Id into g
            select new
            {
                g.Placa,
                g.Descricao,
                g.Consumo,
                g.QuilometrosPercorridos
            });
```

### View

```
@model IEnumerable<dynamic>

<div class="panel-heading">
    <ul class="list-inline">
        <li> <h4>Período:</h4></li>
        <li>@ViewBag.dataInicial Até</li>
        <li> @ViewBag.dataFinal</li>
    </ul>
</div>    

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Placa
            </th>

            <th>
                Descrição
            </th>
            <th>
                Combustivel Gasto
            </th>

            <th>
                Km Percorrido
            </th>
            <th>
                Gasto
            </th>    
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>    
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr class="odd gradeX">
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Placa)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descricao)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Consumo) Litros
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuilometrosPercorridos) Km
                </td>
                <td>
                    R$ @ViewBag.TotalValorEmDinheiro
                </td>
            </tr>
        }    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Atenção que o código não foi testado, pode precisar de alguns ajustes.

Comment: tentei dessa maneira, porém, a parte onde está: g.Placa. g.Descricao... etc, da erro,pois não tem essa propriedade para o "g". aparece somente propriedades como g.GroupBu(), g.ToList().. etc

Answer (score 1):

Altere o tipo do modelo para `IGrouping<int, GaragemModel.Vr>` que não haverá nenhuma mudança de comportamento e deixará de dar erro.

Comment: Alterei, para IGrouping<string, GaragemModel.Vr>, mas ainda continua com o erro

Comment: Corrigi o código, o correto é `IGrouping<int, GaragemModel.Vr>`